# Is it undefined behavior to refer to class members in an initialiser list?

Tags: c++

Let's say I have the following:

```
class A {
   B member1;
   C member2;
public:
   A();
};

class B {
public:
   C& ref_to_c;
   B( C& ref_to_c );
};

class C {
 ...
};
```

B requires that a reference to C be provided on its constructor. If class A provides C, is it legal to specify A's initialiser list as the following...

```
A() : member1( B( member2 ) ) {}
```

That is to say, does member2 exist in the initialiser list phase, or is this **undefined behaviour**?

Comment: member1 is initialized before member 2.. I am not sure about UB but I think something wrong gonna happen

Comment: BTW,  GCC 4.9.2 did not complain at all

Comment: @Galik `member2` isn't a temporary, the temporary `B` is initialized for `member1` and calls the copy constructor or move constructor, nothing wrong here.

Comment: @GillBates yeah I misread it :)

Comment: @GillBates the initialization order will not play any role here? I mean when initializing the member 1, the member 2 will not be constructed yet. isn't it a problem or I missed something?

Comment: Note that it appears to be currently unclear whether this is valid or not.  C++ requires that a reference be initialized to refer to a valid object, however "valid object" isn't clearly defined. There is a standing defect report related to this: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#453

Answer (score 14):

Intialization is as follows:

> 5 Initialization shall proceed in the following order:
>
> — First, and only for the constructor of the most derived class as
>   described below, virtual base classes shall be initialized in the
>   order they appear on a depth-first left-to-right traversal of the
>   directed acyclic graph of base classes, where “left-to-right” is the
>   order of appearance of the base class names in the derived class
>   base-specifier-list.
>
> — Then, direct base classes shall be initialized in declaration order
>   as they appear in the base-specifier-list (regardless of the order of
>   the mem-initializers).
>
> — **Then, nonstatic data members shall be initialized in the order
>   they were declared in the class definition (again regardless of the
>   order of the mem-initializers).**
>
> — Finally, the body of the constructor is executed. [Note: the
>   declaration order is mandated to ensure that base and member
>   subobjects are destroyed in the reverse order of initialization. ]

---

Which basically means that `member1` will always be initialized before `member2`. So, `B`'s constructor will run first. 
Even if you'd call them in reverse order explictly  in `A`'s constructor:

```
A() : member2(foo), member1(bar) {}
```

it *doesn't* make a difference. Now, referencing an uninitialized object is not UB by itself but it can be depending on `B`'s constructor. You should switch the order of declaration:

```
C member2;
B member1;
```

Answer (score 4):

You are making up `member1` that contains a reference to `memebr2`.
That is not constructed yet, but the compiler already knows where it will be (so it can provide a reference).

It will work, but will be UB if you try -for example in B ctor- to access the `ref_to_c` value in some kind of expression, since the reference is actually aliasing an uninitialized memory, that will be initialized during member2 construction, that would happen later.

The same problem will be in B destructor, where `member2` will be destroyed before `ref_to_c`.

It will be better if you swap member2 and member1 in A, so that you will initialize the reference with a constructed object, making every possible usage, defined.